# MySQL Join Table which have had same column name

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to join up this two tables which have had same columns name to get end results as follow. How can I do so?

Table 1, (Primary :- key date)

```
-------------------------------
|        date         | value |
-------------------------------
| 2015-05-16 03:21:46 |   2   |
-------------------------------
```

Table 2, (Primary :- key date)

```
-------------------------------
|        date         | value |
-------------------------------
| 2015-05-16 03:21:46 |   3   |
-------------------------------
```

Expecting end result

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|        date         | value(table1) | value(table2) |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 2015-05-16 03:21:46 |       2       |        3      |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.date, t1.value as value1, t2.value as value2
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.date = t2.date
```

Comment: This works, but when the field names a particularly the same, just use the solution provided by @Timo

Answer (score 16):

Just add the table names when you address the columns:

```
SELECT date, table1.value as value1, table2.value as value2
    FROM table1
    JOIN table2 USING (date)
```

This will give you this result:

```
-----------------------------------------
|        date         | value1 | value2 |
-----------------------------------------
| 2015-05-16 03:21:46 |   2    |   3    |
-----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the above sql that you provided. It thrown errors.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'table1.value' in 'field list'. Btw, Tony had a complete answer.